# Merge update commands into one command possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on below is it possible merge into all three update commands into one update commands with all conditions?
Please provide any samples that would help to me.

```
    UPDATE T1 
    SET STRING2 = I.ResultString, 
        CS_ATTR_020 = I.masonStatus,
        CLASSIFICATION = I.newClassification 
    FROM DOC T1 
    INNER JOIN #InsertedTempTable I ON T1.DB_ZZ_ID=I.ZZ_ID --T1.DOC_KEY=I.docKey AND T1.REVISION=I.docRevision


   UPDATE T3 
   SET CS_ATTR_020 = 2,  
       STRING2 = REPLACE(STRING2, 'RELEASED', 'OBSOLETE') 
    FROM DOC T3 
    INNER JOIN  #InsertedTempTable I ON T3.DB_ZZ_ID=I.ZZ_ID  --T3.DOC_KEY=I.docKey AND  T3.REVISION=I.docRevision
    WHERE STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 1 and CS_ATTR_020 <> 2   AND STRING2 LIKE 'RELEASED%' 

  UPDATE T4  
  SET CS_ATTR_020 = 1,  
      STRING2 = REPLACE(STRING2, 'OBSOLETE', 'RELEASED') 
  FROM DOC T4 
  INNER JOIN  #InsertedTempTable I ON T4.DB_ZZ_ID=I.ZZ_ID    --T4.DOC_KEY=I.docKey AND  T4.REVISION=I.docRevision
  WHERE STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 0 and CS_ATTR_020 = 2  AND STRING2 LIKE 'OBSOLETE%'
```

Thanks for help advance.

Comment: In SQL Server, an `update` statement only affects one table at a time.  You can wrap them all into a single transaction.

Comment: You could perhaps use a view with an insteadof trigger. But doubt you would want to do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are updating the same table in the three update statements, then you can do it in one update query using the `CASE` express as following:

```
UPDATE t
SET CS_ATTR_020 = CASE WHEN STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 1 and CS_ATTR_020 <> 2   AND STRING2 LIKE 'RELEASED%' THEN 2  
                       WHEN STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 0 and CS_ATTR_020 = 2  AND STRING2 LIKE 'OBSOLETE%'   THEN 1
                       ELSE I.masonStatus END,
    STRING2 = CASE WHEN STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 1 and CS_ATTR_020 <> 2   AND STRING2 LIKE 'RELEASED%' THEN REPLACE(STRING2, 'RELEASED', 'OBSOLETE') 
                   WHEN STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 0 and CS_ATTR_020 = 2  AND STRING2 LIKE 'OBSOLETE%' THEN REPLACE(STRING2, 'OBSOLETE', 'RELEASED') 
    ELSE I.ResultString END,
    CLASSIFICATION = CASE WHEN (STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 1 and CS_ATTR_020 <> 2   AND STRING2 LIKE 'RELEASED%')
                               OR (STATUS = 7 and OBSOLETE = 0 and CS_ATTR_020 = 2  AND STRING2 LIKE 'OBSOLETE%' )
                        THEN t.CLASSIFICATION ELSE I.newClassification END
FROM DOC AS T
INNER JOIN  #InsertedTempTable I ON T.DB_ZZ_ID=I.ZZ_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AshokEerla - You're welcome, please accept the answer if it is helpful :D